# Different Java version running in command prompt vs. Windows control panel

Tags: java, command-prompt

I am having some trouble getting a Jar file I have created to run. The program works fine in Eclipse but when I compile and create a runnable JAR it does not work. I did troubleshooting in the command prompt and discovered I was getting the error that means the incorrect version of Java is running. I had this problem before with my program and updated my Java to the required 1.7 and it began working in Eclipse.

The confusing thing now is that when I go to the control panel and go into the Java configuration and click "about" I can see that version 1.7 is active. When I go into the command prompt however and look for the current Java version it returns Java 1.6 hence why I am unable to run the JAR.

Why would I have one version showing in the control panel and another in the command prompt, and how do I fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need to set the current java into the PATH variable.

Comment: Uninstall all versions of Java and install the latest version you'd like to use (Java 8 Update 66 works brilliantly). This fixes all PATH issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Location for path]
Command prompt will run whatever version which is there in the path variable.